# Dns.GetHostEntry always give me the old dns ip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dns, ip

I'm using dns to ip script but it always give me the old ip ( maybe it using cache or something like that ) how i can get the new dns ip ?

```
            var ips = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("mann.chickenkiller.com").AddressList;
        foreach (var ip in ips)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ip.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: flush the host machines dns cache?  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498337/is-there-a-way-to-flush-the-dns-cache-from-a-c-sharp-wpf-app-on-xp-vista-win

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns  not working

Comment: well, what does your system's command line tell you if you request the resolved dns ( eg by ping ) ? is that Ip adress correct? I stronlgy believe, that your computer, router, gateway whatever, still has it cached

Comment: @Najzero it give me old ip too

Comment: hm, try `tracert` on your hostname - maybe one of the nodes on the route notices the changed DNS/IP combination

Comment: @Najzero it give me the old ip too

Comment: For readers, if flushdns doesn't work, check you hosts file.