# GetHostEntry returns local computername instead of DNS name

Tags: c#, dns

I have a domain joined computer with a literal computername of "mycomputername". It has a DHCP entry and DNS record with literal name "mydnsname". Yes, the local computername and DNS are different.

When I query our DNS servers using reverse **NSLOOKUP**, the expected name of "mydnsname" is returned.

However, if I use C# code below on the local machine, the local name "mycomputername" is returned.

```
string ipaddress="123.456.789.123"; //but my Real network IP
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipaddress);
Console.WriteLine hostEntry.HostName;
```

This is unexpected. As far as I am aware, it should query DNS?

I made sure I named my computer something that has never been in DNS, so I know DNS cache is not getting in the way at this stage. If I locally rename the computer, restart, and run the code again - the updated computername is returned.

If I modify DNS, that modified DNS name is never returned - when run on the local machine. *If I run the code on a different machine, but query the same IP, it returns the expected DNS entry*.

I have attempted to flush the cache, but this has no effect:
[Is there a way to flush the DNS cache from a C# WPF app? (on XP, Vista, Win7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498337/is-there-a-way-to-flush-the-dns-cache-from-a-c-sharp-wpf-app-on-xp-vista-win/5148251)

NSLOOKUP command returns the correct name.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277582/how-do-i-clear-system-net-client-dns-cache

Comment: @RandRandom, Tried a few solutions in that thread - the main answer of `ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout` makes no difference, nor does the use of `DnsFlushResolverCache();` which I already tried with the DllImport. `request.Keepalive` is of no use in this context.

Comment: IIRC, Dns.GetHostEntry() queries the \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file first. Is mycomputername defined there?

Comment: @TerryCarmen hosts file is empty.

Comment: If the DNS lookup fails, it will use NETBIOS name resolution using LHOSTS and as any defined WINS server.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I don't believe it is failing - NSLOOKUP on the same machine returns the correct DNS name, and if I run the code with a different IP, it returns the correct DNS name for the remote machine. It almost seems like it is checking NETBIOS _first_ since the IP is for the local machine... I would also expect an exception if lookup failed (I see an exception with an IP that has no DNS).

Comment: @MrBeatnik Sorry, I'm all out of ideas, except that you could fire up wireshark and see what's happening (or not happening)

Comment: @TerryCarmen Thanks for the input. I just have to fallback to Process and RedirectStandardOutput using nslookup. Which works. But I hate it.